# Xml margin left and layout Paramters margin left

Tags: android

I am wondering, when I get the layout Paramters in the code from a view like imageview and then using the code
Param.leftMargin to get left margine then this gets the location of the view on the screen in terms of X value

However if I set left margin using xml on the view then this is saying how far the view it is from its current location without margin.

Do they have different meaning or is my understanding wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first assertion is wrong: reading `leftMargin` from the layout parameters tells you the left margin of the view, not the X position on the screen. They will happen to be the same if the parent container is at the left edge of the screen (X of parent is 0) and it respects the left margin setting (not a given for custom layout containers).

Comment: Ohhhhh I see, so what happens when I use a relativelayout and I center a view in the middle of the screen (vertically and horizontally) with no margins added to the xml? Will the leftmargin be 0 or would it be say (300 on 600 screen width)? In this case the parent container(the main layout) is filling the screen.

Comment: @Snake - If you add no margins in the XML, the `leftMargin` field of the layout should be the default value of 0. I think that if you use `layout_centerHorizontal` then the `RelativeLayout` will ignore the left/right margins for the purpose of positioning that view. However, it should respect the margins for other views placed to the left/right of that child.